# undefined method `permit' for :like:Symbol

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is probably really stupid but, I don't get why this happens.
I have this method.

```
 def vote_params
    params.fetch(:vote, :like, :hate, :movie_id, {}).permit(:like, :hate, :movie_id)
 end
```

And I call the method that calls it (a default scaffold create method) like this.

```
<td><%= link_to Vote.where(movie_id: movie.id, like: true).count, upvote_path( :like => true, :hate => false, :movie_id => movie.id) %></td>
```

My route is

```
  get 'vote/movies' => 'votes#create', as: :upvote
```

What am I missing?

Comment: we need to see your console log, the part where it shows how is your request parameters. What I can tell now is that I found it really weird `params.fetch(:vote, :like, :hate, :movie_id, {})` usually we fetch only one symbol or two, you have 4 already, exactly the same of the permit ones...

Comment: try `params.permit(:like, :hate, :movie_id)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
params.fetch(:vote, :like, :hate, :movie_id, {})
```

that part is not good, if you need to get parameters of separated scopes you need to do something like this.

```
def vote_params
  params.require('vote').permit(:parameter1, :parameter2)
end

def like_params
  params.require('like').permit(:parameter1, :parameter2)
end

def hate_params
  params.require('hate').permit(:parameter1, :parameter2)
end
```

But I believe that the following is what you need

```
def vote_params
   params.permit(:like, :hate, :movie_id)
end
```

Comment: True, my mistake was that I fetched the same params I permitted, so this created a conflict.

Comment: Fixed! Thank you very much